# Response format from Custom Query different from PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, jpa, pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a simple spring-boot application which contains a Repository that extends `JpaRespository` (which in turn extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`:

```java
@RestController
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CatalogueOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<CatalogueOrder, Long>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<CatalogueOrder> {

    @GetMapping("/orderStatusNot")
    Page<CatalogueOrder> findByOrderStatusNot(String orderStatus, Pageable page);
}
```

In addition to the `JpaRepository` which provides basic CRUD/paging/sorting endpoints, I've created a custom query/endpoint using method naming - `findByOrderStatusNot`.

The default findAll() method defined in `PagingAndSortingRepository` appears to return a `Page<T>`, the same as I defined in `findByOrderStatusNot`. However, their actual JSON responses appear much different.

**/catalogueOrders** returns roughly:

```
_embedded:
  catalogueOrders: [
    catalogueOrder + _links
  ]
_links:
  self
  profile
  search
page:
  size
  totalElements
  totalPages
  number
```

**orderStatusNot** returns roughly:

```
content: [
  {catalogueOrder}...
]
pageable:
pageable:
  sort:
    sorted
    unsorted
    empty
  offset
  pageSize
  pageNumber
  paged
  unpaged
last
totalElements
totalPages
size
number
sort:
  sorted
  unsorted
  empty
numberOfElements
first
empty
```

Why does the default provided endpoint provide such different results? And how can I make my endpoint consistent with `findAll()`?

Comment: Is `Page<CatalogueOrder> findByOrderStatusNot(String orderStatus, Pageable page);` giving you some response or not??

Comment: if I try _/catalogueOrders/search/findByOrderStatusNot?orderStatus=delayed_ it does return same ouput as _/catalogueOrders_ see [code on github page-find-all](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/page-find-all/tree/master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first output is `Hypertext Application Language  (hal)` created from the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotations method.

The other output is a simple page returned from the `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` that is missing all the links.

So the main problem is that you mix spring data rest with query-dsl-jpa. They return different media types.

If you want to stick with your dependencies you can try to disable hal by using `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`, but I guess the responses will still be different.

I would suggest to get rid of the spring-data-rest dependency. Just use a controller that points to the findAll of the 
`JpaRepository` and other methods you want to use. Another advantage would also be that your application is much more declarative, meaning you have to explicitly open and describe your endpoints.